# Python wrap code without adding a new line (backslash)

Tags: python, word-wrap

So I have this code that i want to wrap, and i have looked for solutions, most people say to use '\' but when i print the msg from the exception, it splits the string with the new line character

```
raise specialExceptions.ConnectError("There was a \
                                      connect issue")
```

this prints as:

```
There was a 
connect issue
```

I want to wrap the code but output it as one line, how do i do this. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use implicit string concatenation.

```
raise specialExceptions.ConnectError("There was a "
                                     "connect issue")
```

Two string literals appearing adjacent to one another will be merged into a single string. The two literals can appear on different lines; intervening whitespace is not counted, due to Python's implicit line continuation inside parentheses.

Comment: Yeps, but NielZ already published this solution (only that he forgot to use markup and his code didn't appear formatted)

Comment: It was not showing on the page when I submitted my answer. We posted virtually simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Just enclose the strings with quotes on each line
This shall work:

```
raise specialExceptions.ConnectError("There was a "
                                 "connect issue")
```

Comment: please learn how markup works, it'll help you in writing answers in the future